# Change color of GIT branch in OS X terminal

Tags: macos, git, terminal

Is it possible to change color of the GIT branch name in OSX Terminal depending on git status. IE `[green]master[/green]` when files are in sync and `[red]master[/red]` when there's files to commit?

Comment: You could probably write some kind of Bash script or function to add to your git prompt configuration. There might be something built-in for it too, but I don't know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you install [ZSH](http://www.zsh.org/) and see it.
It is working on my mac.